# GeoPandas geofencing problem set up

Tags: python, geopandas, geofencing

I’m a Data Scientist but very new to geospatial analysis so I’m looking for some advice how approach a problem.

I’m trying to determine the speeds of cars that approach traffic lights within 200 ft.  Here’s the data that I have:

- Traffic light position (lat, lon)
- Position of car (lat, lon), data acquired every 15 seconds
- Speed of car (kph), data acquired every 15 seconds

I’m assuming that I need to create a 200 ft radius geofence at each traffic light.  When the car is inside the geofence then note the speed.  I’m not sure how to do this.  Should I create a geopandas data frame for the traffic lights and the car positional and speed data?  I’m not sure how to filter data inside and outside the traffic light geofence.

I’m just looking for some advice for how to approach the problem using Python.

Comment: And this is an example of a question that [does not necessarily need code](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5417/2856). It's asking for general advice/approach, not how to resolve a specific coding issue.

Comment: Can you share your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet is untested because I don't have data, but I think/hope it will get you started. Inline comments explain what is happening and why:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read your traffic light data
lights = gpd.read_file("traffic_lights.gpkg")
# Reproject to a projected crs, to be able to calculate distances. With lat-lon data you can only calculate in degrees.
lights_proj = lights.to_crs(epsg=32662)
# Calculate buffer of 200 feet (recalculated to meter) around each traffic light
lights_buffer = lights_proj.buffer(200*0.3048)

# Read your car data
cars = gpd.read_file("cars.gpkg")
# Reproject to the same (projected) crs as the traffic lights so the data is compatible and can be compared.
cars_proj = cars.to_crs(epsg=32662)

# Do a spatial join to only keep the cars inside the traffic light buffers
cars_in_lights_buffer = gpd.sjoin(cars_proj, lights_buffer)
```

More information about the operations used can be found in the geopandas documentarion: [read_file](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file), [buffer](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html#Buffer), [sjoin](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas.sjoin)